# New field not added to database when Customizing the registration form for FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using FOSUserBundle and I am tring to Customizing the registration form by following this toturial:

https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/fosuserbundle/customize-forms

but I have an issue:

1- The new field "nom " is not visible in the database even after updating the database using :

php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

the result:

Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.

[image]

register_content.html.twig:

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

<h1> </h1>
{{ form_start(form, {'method': 'post', 'action': path('fos_user_registration_register'), 'attr': {'class': 'fos_user_registration_register'}}) }}

<label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12  form-control-label " for="name" >Nom d'utilisateur <span class="required"></span>
</label>
<div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
    {{ form_widget(form.username, {'attr': {'class' : 'form-control '}}) }}
</div>

<label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12  form-control-label " for="name" >E-mail <span class="required"></span>
</label>
<div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
    {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr': {'class' : 'form-control '}}) }}
</div>


<label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12  form-control-label " for="name" >Password <span class="required"></span>
</label>
<div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
    {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword, {'attr': {'class' : 'form-control '}}) }}
</div>


<label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12  form-control-label " for="name" >Nom <span class="required"></span>
</label>
<div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
    {{ form_widget(form.nom, {'attr': {'class' : 'form-control '}}) }}
</div>

<div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" />
</div>

{ form_end(form) }}
```

**RegistrationFormType:**

```
class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('nom');
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return BaseRegistrationFormType::class;
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'storeData.form.registration';
    }
}
```

User.php

```
/**
 *  @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="StoreDataBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name=" `user` ")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups= 
{"Registration", "Profile"})
 * @Assert\Length(
 *     min=3,
 *     max=255,
 *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
 *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
 *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
 * )*/

    protected $nom;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getNom()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $nom
     */
    public function setNom($nom)
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;
    }
```

**config.yml**

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: StoreDataBundle\Entity\User
    service:                               # this lines
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift # this lines
    from_email:
        address: "hello@aquanote.com"
        sender_name: "AquaNote Postman"

    registration:
        form:
            type: StoreDataBundle\Form\RegistrationFormType
```

**service.yml**

```
storeData.form.registration:
        class: StoreDataBundle\Form\RegistrationFormType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

**security.yml**

```
security:

    encoders:
        StoreDataBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt


    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:

        main:

            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            anonymous: true

            logout: true

            remember_me:
                secret: '%secret%'
```

**UPDATE : User.orm.yml**

```
StoreDataBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: StoreDataBundle\Repository\UserRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Update:

I found my error: I had an yml file and annotation thats why it didn't work

Comment: Will be better using migrations in symfony.
And maybe doctrine cache clear can help you.

`
 php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata 
 php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query  
 php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
`

Comment: @NairiAbgaryan I had used those command but nothing happend!! always the field 'nom' dosn't appear in the user table!!!

Comment: Can you add doctrine config?

Comment: @Eakethet I have updated my post

Comment: @NairiAbgaryan  is it because my Registration file named RegistrationFormType should it be just RegistrationType!!!